# Изменение цвета на случайный

Tags: delphi

Мне надо поменять случайный системный цвет поменять на случайный цвет. Вот что у меня получилось:

[image]

В чём ошибка?

Comment: Aльзо, Random используется неверно - http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE2/en/System.Random

Answer (score 3):

> Variable required

Смотрим сигнатуру процедуры

```
procedure SetSysColors(Changes: Integer; var SysColor: Integer; var ColorValues: Longint);
```

у `SetSysColors` второй и третий параметры должны быть именно переменными.

Comment: Спасибо!!! А почему именно переменными?!

Comment: Это связано с тем, что соответствующая WinAPI-шная функция требует в качестве параметров указатели. 

    BOOL SetSysColors(
      int cElements,         
      CONST INT *lpaElements,
      CONST COLORREF *lpaRgbValues   
    );

Comment: Хороший вопрос. На самом деле ругайте Баглад за это, сигнатура неверная.

Comment: @Nofate, как раз наоборот же! У вас же прямо в копипасте `__in const` написано.

Comment: Сегодня конечно понедельник, но `__in const` я у себя в упор не вижу.

Comment: Ну хорошо, `CONST`. Стало лучше или ждем среды? :-P

Comment: И? `INT *lpaElements` - указатель на инту. Когда ТС вызывает `rgb` возвращаемый результат кладется куда-нибудь в `eax` и компилятор никак не преобразует это в адрес. Поэтому и требуется в явном виде переменная. 

    // чую, что вы хотите меня на чем то подловить или уже подловили ))
    //  /* а еще мне кажется, что @karamdro4 - мой личный ангел-тролль ) */

Comment: Подумайте головой и тролли перестанут мерещиться ;-) Эти параметры передаются по ссылке. Модификатор - `const` (здесь - Си). В доках аннотатор `__in`. Зачем в паскальной сигнатуре нужен `var`? Это ж типичный случай, где должен быть `const` (а теперь речь о Паскале). В ХЕ исправлено, кстати говоря.

Comment: мы обсуждаем косячную обертку или то, почему нужно передавать переменные явно? ) У меня в 2010 тоже `const`, но это не отменяет того факта, что нужна переменная.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте перед api функцией всавить

```
Randomize;
```